# Draw Borders for a ListBox Control In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, listbox, paint

I use this code to set Borders for controls:

```
        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, Panel1.ClientRectangle, Color.Silver, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
```

I write this code in controls **Paint event** but there is not any Paint event for ListBox controls

Can anyone solve this please?

Comment: The ListBox is a very archaic control. You can UserPaint it by deriving a custom class from it, use `SetStyle(UserPaint, True)` and then use `Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)` to draw your stuff. However this messes extremely with the drawing of items. Consider using a `DatagridView` instead.

Comment: Thanks, But DataGridView has his own problems!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unfortunately there is no paint event for listBox , for drawing border to list box you can dock listBox in container then make border for container .

For example:
You can dock the listBox in panel,set the padding for panel to 2,2,2,2
set the border style for listBox to none.
and then draw border for panel or set backcolor for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My ListBox has a border now! (: